# How to parse from String to Integer[][][] efficiently?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

The files I work with usually are the form of:

> {0 0},{0 0}
>
> {0 0 0 0},{0 0 0 0},{0 0 0 0},{0 0 0 0}

So I need a `Integer[][][]` to store an array of matrix.

I tried:

```
  String path = "file.txt";
    String[] var = (String[]) Files.lines(Path.of(path)).toArray();
    for(String s:var) {
        String[] var2 = s.split(",");
    }
```

At that point I realized that there has to be a better way to read this. I have tried using `streams` but I don't know.

Comment: What do you mean by "efficiently"? The *simplest* way would probably be to use a JSON parser, after adding `{ }` around the text.

Comment: Stream API doesn't really like working with base arrays (prefers Collections API like `List`) so you are unlikely to be impressed by the code required to generate your matrix. Keep going with your method (but please make them `int[][][]` not `Integer[][][]`)

Comment: Efficient: don't call `toArray` to read all the lines into memory at once, use `Stream.forEach` instead (or `Stream.map`). Don't use `split` with a regex, but use `charAt` and `indexOf` to first count how many elements there are in each subsection of the String, then allocate an `Integer[]` or `Integer[][]` of the right size, then go over the String again to parse into those arrays. The question is: do you need that efficiency? If this is part of something that runs multiple times per second on large files, then probably yes. Otherwise, it depends.

Comment: I usually upvote but my reputation isn’t high enough to be visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, then each line corresponds to a different cell in your array in the first dimension, each set of french braces is the second dimension, and the integers inside the french braces are the third dimension.

That means you can:

1. Define a method `a()` that takes a String like `{1 2 3 4}` and returns an Integer[] with these numbers.
2. Define a method `b()` that takes a line like  `{1 2 3},{4 5 6}` which splits the line by `,` and calls `a()` once for each token and then returns an `Integer[][]` with all the `Integer[]` results
3. Define a method `c()` which takes an array of lines and calls `b()` once for each line and returns an `Integer[][][]` filled with all the `Integer[][]` results